# How do you write a link containing a closing bracket in markdown syntax?

Tags: syntax, markdown

Markdown syntax for a link is pretty simple:

```
[Example](http://example.com/)
```

produces:

> [Example](http://example.com/)

But what if the link itself contains a closing bracket?

```
[Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages))
```

produces:

> [Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_%28programming_languages))

which is obviously broken.

**Edit**

Putting the url in quotes does not work

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can try to escape the character:

```
[Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_\(programming_languages\))
```

You can also encode the characters

```
[Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_%28programming_languages%29)
```

Comment: Yes, just discovered this myself, thanks (although your escape slashes are the wrong way round).

Comment: This is not working for me. The answer by @ovhaag actually works!

Comment: the first approach works for me (escaping the characters) and is more readable

Comment: regarding links inside of a markdown file, just found out that you can just omit the brackets

Answer (score 48):

Sometimes you need to encode ) with %29.

```
[Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages%29)
```

E.g.: This was the only method I could find to get a correct Markdown preview in the Atom Editor.

Comment: also seems only way in Jupyter notebook, accepted answer did not work for me.

Comment: Great idea! I work with lots of systems that "support" markdown, but most of the other tricks don't work. This seems like the most likely solution to universally work.

Comment: If you're going to escape any of the parentheses in the link, it seems better to escape them all.  It helps avoid you perceiving a false pairing.  With only the close parenthesis escaped, it looks like `programming_languages%29` is parenthesized, on first glance.  `[Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_%28programming_languages%29)` is clearer for the reader/editor of the MarkDown...

Answer (score 9):

I have found that using `<` around `>` the url seems to solve the problem.
In the two internal systems we use that use markdown.
Your mileage may vary with other systems.

```
[Test](<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security)>)
```

[Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security))

Comment: Tall flowers of thanks! This answer was the cleanest, easiest approach. I used it to create _table of contents_ with _anchor_ links in a Jupyter notebook. When a heading includes parentheses, escaping them is as easy as putting the whole link inside `<` and `>`, as in `[title (more info)](<#title-(more-info)>)`.

Comment: Doesn't work in reddit (but the %29 solution does).

Comment: Reporting in for vim: this does not work, but %28/%29 does.

Comment: This also does work in Zulip!

Answer (score 5):

The most reliable way I've found to do this is to use reference-style links instead of inline links.

```
Here is the wikipedia article on [Syntax][1]

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages)
```

renders correctly as

> Here is the wikipedia article on [Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages))

I've found that with some sites, percent-escaping the parentheses will break URLs, especially anchors. For example, at least in my version of Firefox, this Android documentation link doesn't take me directly to the method [with percent encoding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29).
But this one with a [reference-style link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) does.

```
For example, at least in my version of Firefox, this Android documentation link
doesn't take me directly to the method [with percent encoding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29). 
But this one with a [reference-style link][2] does.
```

Comment: For reference: it seems this breaks when the URL has only a closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP):

> URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the [ASCII character-set](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp).

So, you need to encode any special characters that is not a `ASCII character` into its respective `ASCII character`.

In your case, the characters for brackets or parenthesis are

- open bracket `(` - `%28`
- closing bracket `)` - `%29`

---

You can use [this website](https://www.urlencoder.io/) to get the encoded url of any website link.

Comment: A similar question is [asked here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13509/381523), which has more examples on how to solve this.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to scape it at all.

On GitHub, I've just done the following without any problems:

```
[Slowloris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security))
```

Actually, even here you can use it directly, as you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security)).